# How to overwrite the current line with the new line to keep only one line of data

Tags: ruby, loops

What I want to do is this, read from a file, output each line of the file on one line, and if the output does not match the matching input, go to the next on the same line, for example:

Text file:

```
hello
goodbye
yes
no
why
maybe
okay
tomorrow
```

Code:

```
def compare(input)
  File.readlines('test.txt').each do |word|
    if word == input
      puts "Found a match! #{word} == #{input}"
    else
      loop do
        puts "Comparing #{input} to #{word}" #<= Overwrite the current compared word, with the new compared word
        $stdout.flush        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I go about doing this properly? I believe that I can use the `\r` to remove the line however when I add the `\r` and this is run it output:

```
Comparing why to word

Comparing why to word

Comparing why to word

Comparing why to word

Comparing why to word

Comparing why to word

Comparing why to word
```

---

The closest I can get to an example is if you copy @Sculper's answer and run it in `IRB`

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  print "test #{i}\r" # Courtesy of @Sculpur
  $stdout.flush
  sleep(1)
end
```

Comment: can give example input and expected output ? right now I don't understand what you want to achieve :)

Comment: @niceman It's going to be hard to give an example of that, what I mean is this I want the words from the file to appear in place of the last word from the file, for example: `Comparing why to hello` the hello will be replaced with `goodbye` with out going to a new line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We need a usable example of the input and desired output. It helps us help you, and it helps others in the future understand your question and whether it matches the problem they're seeing, which is what SO is for. "What I want to do is this, read from a file, output each line of the file on one line, and if the output does not match the matching input, go to the next on the same line" doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `print` instead of `puts` if you want to replace a single line of output.  For example:

```
(1..5).each do |i|
  print "test #{i}\r"
  $stdout.flush
  sleep(1)
end
```

That said, I doubt this code alone will solve your problem - the example output you gave suggests that your code is getting stuck in an infinite loop.  As Max mentioned, this is because your `loop do` is not only redundant (you're already iterating over the words gathered from the file), but there is no exit condition - it will never stop.

```
loop do
  puts "Comparing #{input} to #{word}"
  $stdout.flush        
end
```

Should be replaced with:

```
print "Comparing #{input} to #{word}"
$stdout.flush
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, however I want the word from the file to be replaced instead

Comment: @Donovan It's not being replaced because your code is stuck in an infinite loop.  I've updated the answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `loop do` is creating an infinite loop. I don't see any reason to add a loop here. Also, I think you need to call `chomp` on your `word` variable to remove the trailing newline character.

i.e.

```
def compare(input)
  File.readlines('test.txt').each do |word|
    word = word.chomp # removes training '\n' character
    if word == input
      puts "Found a match! #{word} == #{input}"
    else
      puts "Comparing #{input} to #{word}"
    end
  end
end
```

In your code, you say that `puts "Comparing #{input} to #{word}"` will overwrite the current compared word with the new compared word, but this isn't true. You're not assigning  variables or changing application state here at all  - just logging something to console. Unless I'm unaware of some approach you're taking with `$stdout.flush`, I think it's unnecessary.

If all else, fails, a good way to debug is to install either `pry` or `byebug` and place a breakpoint in your code. Then you can inspect the values of your variables at runtime.

Comment: That's not at all what I wanted to do? I want the information produced on the same line, and to overwrite the word until it finds a match

Comment: You still haven't showed an example output. I don't really know what you mean "overwrite each word until it finds a match"

Comment: Run this in IRB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890340/how-to-overwrite-the-current-line-with-the-new-line-to-keep-only-one-line-of-dat/37890614#37890614 That's the closest to an example I can get, it's @Sculper's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def compare(input)
  arr = File.read('test.txt').split("\n")
  arr.each do |word|
    print "Comparing #{word} -> #{input}\r"
    $stdout.flush
    sleep(1)
    if word == input
      puts "Successfully found match! #{word} -> #{input}"
      exit
    end
  end
end
```

The output will all be on the same line, and will replace the word. It's not perfect, but it will work. The key is to make sure that your success output is longer then the testing output.